# Does anyone know a Jersey client proxy implementation like Apache CXF offers for REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, cxf

the Apache CXF project offers a proxy based client implementation for REST services. This looks like:

```
Resource resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create( baseAddress, Resource.class )
```

Does anyone know a similar implementation for Jersey?

I spotted an approach using `@HyperMediaController` annotations, but I want to stick to JSR-311 default annotations like `@Path` and `@Get` ...

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created an own implementation. See [utils-apl-derived wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/utils-apl-derived/wiki/RestClientFactoryJersey) therefore.

Answer (score 6):

A proxy implementation exists, but unfortunately it's not even mentioned in [Jersey Client API documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) (neither in [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)) as of version 2.22.1.

What I found was JavaDoc for [WebResourceFactory](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/WebResourceFactory.html), even better is the [package JavaDoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/package-summary.html). Here's a snippet from the JavaDoc on the usage of the WebResourceFactory:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/");
MyResourceIfc resource = WebResourceFactory.newResource(MyResourceIfc.class, target);
```

In Maven you then need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in addition to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found WebResourceFactory miss generic types supports and it's source code was really hard to understand. So we created https://github.com/adaptris/jaxrs-client-proxy and we are currently devloping it.

To use it you need to build a resource:

```
ResourceBuilder builder = new ResourceBuilder();
resource = builder.
    url("https://host/api").
    build(Resource.class);
client = resource.get();
```

Then you can call `client` - which is proxy of your jax-rs annotation described interface (`Resource.class`). You should close a resource after stoping using it as it is recommended by jax-rs client api.

```
resource.close()
```

More details on github [projet](https://github.com/adaptris/jaxrs-client-proxy) page.

Comment: Please add some explanation and code how to use this. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.